# zend debug multiple pages

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-debugger

I have a pretty simple setup:

Apache server, PHP 5.3, Eclipse, PHP Zend Debug Module

When I click on debug it sees my breakpoints and everything works fine. But only for the first page. If I click on a different page within the integrated browser, all breakpoints from that moment forward are ignored. I think it has to do with the fact that the first page's URL is something similar to

```
http://localhost/schedule?start_debug=1&debug_host=127.0.0.1&send_sess_end=1&debug_session_id=1003&original_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fschedule&debug_start_session=1&debug_no_cache=1303403971996&debug_port=10000
```

Whereas pages after do not have these URL debug parameters appended. Is this a limitation with debugging in eclipse, or *is there some way to append these GET parameters to every link I click?* Perhaps a browser extension?

Looking under advanced for my debug configuration, I see that I have "Debug All Pages" checked.

Comment: Try to remove all `Path Mapping` in debug configuration - `PHP Server configuration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently tried the **Xdebug** extension for the same thing, and i can really recommend it.

Xdebug does exactly this, and also sets a Cookie which contains the debug session info, so you can browse through the Website and the debugger will halt on a breakpoint. So it's definately not an eclipse issue.

You could check if the Zend Debug Module does the same thing by calling the above URL in Firefox and checking if a cookie was set.

Greetings and Good Luck